# How to define tab amount and name in Ionic 2 when creating new project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When creating new App in ionic 2, we use this command:

> ionic start --v2 myApp tabs

By default, it creates 3 tabs and pages: Home, Contact and About.
Is it possible to define the number and names of the tabs to be created?

Comment: that template is just for understanding purpose(To understand how navigation works,what is structure etc..) we can always edit number of tabs and tab names in code

Comment: Yes. I actually do that. I just wonder if there is such method, that's all. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't dynamically define the tabs and pages since this is an already made template which is available here [tabs template](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tabs%20'tabs%20template'). However you can still define your own by jumping into the files generated in your project and modifying the tabs.html to show your desired names and the pages inside the pages folder to the pages you want.